# lock объекта по Id

Tags: c#, многопоточность, concurrency, lock, блокировки

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Имеется некий метод,записывающий сущность в бд, примерно такой:

```
public void Update(Foo foo)
{
    UpdateFirstPart(foo.First);
    UpdateSecondPart(foo.Second);
    UpdateThirdPart(foo.Third);
}
```

Foo выглядит примерно так:

```
class Foo 
{
    public int Id;

    public Some1 First;  

    public Some2 Second; 

    public Some3 Third; 
}
```

Смысл тут такой: чтобы корректно выполнить обновление нашей сущности, нужно сделать три шага: `UpdateFirstPart`, `UpdateSecondPart` и `UpdateThirdPart`. Проблема в том, что метод `Update` может выполняться из разных потоков одновременно. Если используются разные экземпляры `foo`, то проблем нет - две сущности параллельно обновляются и всё ок. Проблема возникает, если одновременно обновляются два `Foo` с одинаковыми `Id` В этом случае изменения в одном потоке могут перетирать изменения другого потока, притом в итоге сохранится часть изменений из первого потока и часть из второго, то есть в результате в бд записывается каша. Во избежание этого вполне логичным кажется поместить код в блокировку:

```
public void Update(Foo foo)
{
    lock(_locker) 
    {
        UpdateFirstPart(foo.First);
        UpdateSecondPart(foo.Second);
        UpdateThirdPart(foo.Third);
    }
}
```

Всё работает. Но остаётся проблема, заключающаяся  том, что эта блокировка работает всегда, в том числе и тогда, когда разные потоки обновляют разные экземпляры `Foo` (точнее `Foo` с разными `Id`)? а мне нужна блокировка тоьлко для тех случаев, когда из двух (или более) потоков происходит вызов `Update` для `Foo` с одинаковыми `Id`. Как это сделать? Может быть у кого-то есть идеи на этот счёт?

Comment: Как насчет ```lock(foo)``` ?

Comment: @tym32167 идея неплохая, но теоретически foo может участвовать в другом `lock` за пределами метода `Update`. К тому же это не два одинаковых экземпляра `Foo`, а два разных экземпляра с одинаковыми полями `Id`

Comment: @Pupkin, напрашивается целый словарь `Dictionary<int, object> _locker` и блокировка по `_locker[foo.Id]`. Только вот продумать надо как сделать чтобы словарь не разрастался. Ну и сам словарь должен быть потокобезопасным

Comment: Сделать список Id, которые обновляются в текущий момент. При каждом обновлении проверять список. Если Id уже в списке, то встать в очередь на обновление, иначе добавить id в список и начать обновление.

Comment: Конкретно подобную проблему лучше всего решать через striped lock (фиксированный набор локов, из которых выбирается один по хэшкоду объекта), но это вас не спасет от модификации с разных машин или из разных приложений, поэтому действительно лучше обратиться к возможностям базы данных.

Answer (score 1):

А как вам варинт попробовать это выполнить через [транзакции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Это избавит вас от необходимости писать lock-систему.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    // Start a local transaction.
    SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction();

    // Enlist a command in the current transaction.
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = sqlTran;

    try
    {
        // Execute two separate commands.
        command.CommandText =
          "INSERT INTO Production.ScrapReason(Name) VALUES('Wrong size')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.CommandText =
          "INSERT INTO Production.ScrapReason(Name) VALUES('Wrong color')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Commit the transaction.
        sqlTran.Commit();
        Console.WriteLine("Both records were written to database.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception if the transaction fails to commit.
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        try
        {
            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            sqlTran.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception exRollback)
        {
            // Throws an InvalidOperationException if the connection 
            // is closed or the transaction has already been rolled 
            // back on the server.
            Console.WriteLine(exRollback.Message);
        }
    }
}
```